# Sprite doesn't regenerate in Sprite Kit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, sprite

I am trying to get the sprite to regenerate itself once it moves off of the screen, but no luck.

```
      #import "MyScene.h"

    @implementation MyScene

    -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
      if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
      /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.05 green:0.15 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];

    SKSpriteNode *pole = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:(@"pole")];
    bamboo.position = CGPointMake (30, 0);
    bamboo.size = CGSizeMake(15, 1136);



    [self addChild: pole];

    SKSpriteNode *pole2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:(@"pole")];
    pole2.position = CGPointMake (290, 0);
    pole2.size = CGSizeMake(15, 1136);

    [self addChild: pole2];


    SKSpriteNode *spike = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:(@"spike")];
    spike.position = CGPointMake (45, 600);
    spike.size = CGSizeMake(15, 75);

    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:(0) y:(-10) duration:(.05)];

    [spike runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveDown]];

    [self addChild: spike];


  }
  return self;
 }


 -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
if (_spike.position.y < 250) {


    _spike.position = CGPointMake(45, 600);
 }

}

@end
```

What could be the problem? Xcode does not give me an error, the "spike" node simply moves off the screen and does not reset itself. I have changed the values in the conditional, but the same thing happens. It's like the conditional is being ignored.

Comment: Your conditional checking the location of the spike, will ONLY happen during this block of code when you create the spike, and not every frame. You understand that right ?

Comment: @prototypical That makes sense. Where would I place the conditional if I wanted it to update every frame? I put it in the currentTime update method to no avail.

Comment: Yes, you would put it the update method, and it does work. You likely have implemented it incorrectly. Check out the current answer, that should work. I also suggest that you learn about the debugger early on in your learning, as it will save you tons of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to check Sprite's position in the update method, you can try this;

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

    _spike = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:(@"spike")];
    _spike.position = CGPointMake (45, 600);
    _spike.size = CGSizeMake(15, 75);

    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:(0) y:(-10) duration:(.05)];

    [_spike runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveDown]];

    [self addChild:_spike];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if (_spike.position.y < 250) {

        _spike.position = CGPointMake(45, 600);
    }

}
```

Comment: As much as I would think this works, it does not. Any idea why?

Comment: ohh, did you write your code inside of "if (self = [super initWithSize:size])", other than that this code is working for me, can you tell what kind of error you are getting from xcode

Comment: Sorry, i should've been more clear. It isn't giving me an error, but the sprite node simply moves off of the screen, removes itself, and does not reappear.

Comment: can you edit your post by putting all of your code inside, so I can help you better

Comment: got it :), you have to use same _spikes everywhere, I edited my solution

Comment: Thank you so much! You just solved multiple problems of mine! Thanks again!